# Is this relationship between the radial and cartesian displacements for symmetrically axially loaded cylinders correct?

Tags: symmetry, continuum-mechanics, displacement

The relationship between the radial coordinate $r$ and the Cartesian $x$ and $y$ coordinate is:

$$ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \tag 1 $$

If a cylinder is under a symmetric axial load, a displacement in the longitudinal $z$ direction and radial $r$ direction exists. This is why switching from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates is useful. However, I never found in any book that the relationship between the radial displacement and the cartesian $x$ and $y$ displacement is the following:

$$ u_r^2 = u_x^2 + u_y^2 \tag 2 $$

This correlation makes sense to me if the displacements do not depend on angle $\theta$. But since I never found this in a book, I hope somebody here can confirm this relationship.

In summary, my question is: Is the correlation $(2)$ correct for symmetrically axially loaded cylinders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not correct (see 1, for example)

You should perform a (local) rotation, that is,

\begin{align}
u_x = u_r \cos\theta - u_\theta \sin\theta\, ,\\
u_y = u_r \sin\theta + u_\theta \cos\theta\, ,
\end{align}

or $\{u_\text{cartesian}\} = [Q] \{u_\text{polar}\}$, with

$$[Q] = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta &\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}\, .$$

For the inverse relation, you could invert the expression.

#### References

1. Barber, J. R. Elasticity. Springer Netherlands, 2010. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-90-481-3809-8.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Thank you very much :)